# Relationship between functions given by same rule, but different domains.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

We have a function $1_{x}: P(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by 
$
1_{x}(E) :=
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill 1    \hfill & \text{ if } x \in E\\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{ if } x \not \in E \\
  \end{cases}
$
and a function 
$1_{E}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by 
$
1_{E}(x) :=
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill 1    \hfill & \text{ if } x \in E\\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{ if } x \not \in E \\
  \end{cases}
$

We see that the values of the functions are the same for each choice of $(x,E) \in X \times P(X)$. Does this relation between these two functions have some name? Is there a clean way to express this in form of for instance $Hom_{Set}(X \times P(X), \mathbb{R})$, $Hom_{Set}(X, \mathbb{R})$ or $Hom_{Set}( P(X), \mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions are related by

- The uncurrying isomorphisms $[X\to(\mathcal P(X)\to\mathbb R)]\cong [(X\times\mathcal P(X))\to \mathbb R]$,
- Commutativity of products $[X\times\mathcal P(X)]\cong[\mathcal P(X)\times X]$ and its lift to functions *from* such products (by pre-composition), and
- The currying isomorphism $[(\mathcal P(X)\times X)\to\mathbb R]\cong [\mathcal P(X)\to(X\to\mathbb R)]$.

Sweeping a few of the boring details aside, I would just say that the two (families of) functions are simply two different [curryings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) of the indicator function of the $\in$ relation between $X$ and $\mathcal P(X)$.